# Two different ways to determine $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ .

Tags: calculus, limits

### Method 1: By using Sandwich Theorem

We know that

$$\frac{-1}{x} \leq \frac{\sin x}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x}   $$

Applying limit,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-1}{x} \leq \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} \leq \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}   $$

$$ 0 \leq \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} \leq 0  $$

$$\therefore\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 0$$

### Method 2:

Put $x = \frac{1}{t}$

Then as $x \to \infty$ , $\frac{1}{t} \to 0.$

Equation becomes:
$$\lim_{\frac{1}{t}\to 0}\frac{\sin \frac{1}{t}}{\frac{1}{t}}$$
which is 1.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me out.

Comment: *“Then as $x \to \infty$ , $\frac{1}{t} \to 0.$“* –  That is wrong. $t \to 0$ and $\frac{1}{t}  = x \to \infty$.

Comment: It’s right there in your definition of $t.$ $x=\frac1t$ and $x\to \infty$ means $\frac1t\to \infty.$ This means $t\to 0^+.$

Comment: in method 2, the limit changes to $t\to 0$ not $\frac 1 t\to 0$

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I realized my mistake.

Comment: Try the small angle approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake with the substitution.

If $x=\frac1t$, then as $x\to\infty,\ \frac1t=x\to\infty$, not zero.

The correct way to solve it is to recognise that as $x\to\infty,\ \color{red}{t}\to0^+$ (there's no use in finding where $\frac1t$ goes since it is just $x$ and you wouldn't be using the substitution).

Then, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ becomes:
$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin(1/t)}{(1/t)}=\lim_{t\to0^+}t\sin(1/t)$$

Applying the squeeze theorem (since $t\to0^+,\ t$ is positive and we can multiply by it):
$$-1\leq\sin(1/t)\leq1\implies -t\leq t\sin(1/t)\leq t$$
Taking the limit of all terms:
$$\lim_{t\to0^+}(-t)\leq\lim_{t\to0^+}t\sin(1/t)\leq\lim_{t\to0^+}t$$
$$0\leq\lim_{t\to0^+}t\sin(1/t)\leq0$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{t\to0^+}t\sin(1/t)=0,$$
which is equivalent to the original limit
$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin(1/t)}{(1/t)}=0.$$

Answer (score -1):

The two evaluation are indeed correct but these are two completely different limits. To make them the same we should take $x=\frac 1 t \to \infty$ with $t\to 0^+$ (and not $\frac1t \to 0^+$) and then

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}= \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sin \frac1t}{\frac1t}=0$$

---

**Edit**

As an alternative to sandwich theorem, we can proceed by contradiction assuming that

$$\frac{\sin x}{x}\to L\neq 0$$

but for $x_n= 2\pi n\to \infty$ we obtain

$$\frac{\sin x_n}{x_n}=\frac{\sin\left( 2\pi n\right)}{2\pi n}= 0$$

which is a contradiction.

Therefore if limit exists it must be equal to zero and this finally can be checked by the definition.

Comment: That seems to miss explaining the error. You are correct the reasoning is wrong, but you haven’t pinpointed *why.*

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The error is that we are taking the limit at different "points".

Comment: What’s a “point?” OP is trying to find clarity, because OP knows it was wrong. Find an error in the substitution $x=\frac1t.$ It is literally right there in the question. What was wrong with the substitution? (I’m not one of the downvoters.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes I get your point. I've added something more to make the point clear. Thanks